# I have a problem on setting the date format with strptime() on python. Can't find the right match of values

Tags: python, datetime, parsing

I have the following bit of code:

```
    def process_row(row: 'RowType', dt_format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"):
        start_time = f"{row['Meeting Date'][:10]} {row['Meeting Time'][:5]}"
        print(start_time)

        row.update(
            start_time=datetime.strptime(start_time, dt_format),
            # Zoom expects the `duration` value in minutes.
            duration=int(row['Duration Hr']) * 60 + int(row['Duration Min']),
```

That `print(start_time)` prints `2023-05-12 15:00`, but the `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"` used for `dt_format` can't seem to match the content.

I get the following error:

```
 raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data ' ' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
```

where it seems to me that the ' ' listed on the error refers to the space between the two strings being captured from rows on the second line and/or the space between the formatting symbols (%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), because if I put a character in both, it shows between the quotes on the error.

I have tried passing different formats of data, changing the date information on the excel file from where it is reading the dates, tried passing only the year with four digits and %Y and it still doesnt work.

The intended result is for it to pass as a date object so i can use it as information for creating meetings on Zoom.

I'm new to python, so maybe it is something really obvious escaping me.

As mentioned in comments, it might help for me to post the whole block of code:

```
from zoom_api_helper import ZoomAPI
from datetime import datetime
from zoom_api_helper.models import *

def main():
    zoom = ZoomAPI('REDACTED', 'REDACTED', 'REDACTED')

    col_name_to_kwarg = {'Group Name': 'agenda',
                         'Zoom Username': 'host_email'}

    def process_row(row: 'RowType', dt_format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"):
        start_time = f"{row['Meeting Date'][:10]} {row['Meeting Time'][:5]}"
        print(start_time)

        row.update(
            start_time=datetime.strptime(start_time, dt_format),
            duration=int(row['Duration Hr']) * 60 + int(row['Duration Min']),
        )
        return True

    def update_row(row: 'RowType', resp: dict):
        row['Meeting URL'] = resp['join_url']
        row['Meeting ID'] = resp['id']
        row['Passcode'] = resp['password']

    zoom.bulk_create_meetings(
        col_name_to_kwarg,
        excel_file='./meeting-info.xlsx',
        default_timezone='America/Sao_Paulo',
        process_row=process_row,
        update_row=update_row,
    )
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete, it ends mid-statement and doesn't show how `process_row()` is called, or what the value of `row` is when you call it. If I take your code, and set `row` to be a dictionary that has a correctly formatted `'Meeting Date'` and `'Meeting time'`, the other statements work just fine. You should provide code that shows what the value of `row` is, and if you share code that we can actually run that has the problem, you should share a full stack trace of the error message. Currently, there's just not enough information to help. What does `.update()` do, where does it come from?

Comment: @Grismar Thank you for replying! i updated with rest of it to make it clearer for anyone helping.

Comment: Works fine for me... https://trinket.io/python3/523e380095 I'd double check you're not using tab or something by mistake. (Is the print statement ***definitely*** printing ***exactly*** what you say?)

Comment: I can only replicate your error message if the row values being processed are empty strings. So, your print statement should also print just the single space. The error always includes the WHOLE string being parsed, not just part of it. https://trinket.io/python3/9ed6104eb3 and https://trinket.io/python3/eedcc788eb

Comment: `RowType` in your code would appear to be coming from `zoom_api_helper.models` and is very loosely defined: https://github.com/rnag/zoom-api-helper/blob/main/zoom_api_helper/models.py  It seems very much like it that the error you're getting does not correspond with the print output you also shared, it's as if they were from different runs. It's also still unclear where `.update()` comes from, unless it's the `.update()` method of `dict`. Since `bulk_create_meetings` does no further conversion, the error should already be in `start_time`